# Toggle DropMenu

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a menu with a droplist, using jQuery to the onclick toggle for changing the class from "hide" to "show". Although I cannot figure it out.

Here's what I have:

```
<style type="text/css">
    nav ul li.hide ul {
        display: none;
    }
    nav ul li.show ul {
        display: block;
    }
</style>

<nav>
  <ul>
      <li class="hide">Home
        <ul>
          <li>Dropdown Link</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
 </ul>
</nav>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $('li').toggleClass('hide', 'show');
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $('li').toggleClass('hide', 'show');
  });
</script>
```

To This:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $("li").click(function () {
      $(this).toggleClass("hide show");
   });
  });
</script>
```